# If str_ireplace() doesn't meet php condition

Tags: php

I have a code where I match comma-separated words to text using the `str_ireplace()` function:

```
$words = "word1, word2, word3";
$text = "This is word1 text word2";

if (str_ireplace(explode(', ', $words), '', $text) != $text) {
   /*any logic*/
}
```

Please tell me how can I do the reverse logic? Those. if **nothing is found** or **matched**.

`else {}` does not work.

Full code:

```
function get_matched_categories( $description_every ) {
    $correspondence_tables = get_field( 'correspondence_table', 'option' );
    $default_categories = get_field( 'default_categories', 'option' );
    if ( is_array( $correspondence_tables ) ) {
        $arr_cat = array();
        foreach ( $correspondence_tables as $child_correspondence ) {

            if ( str_ireplace( explode( ', ', $child_correspondence['keywords'] ), '', $description_every ) != $description_every ) {
                array_push( $arr_cat, get_cat_ID( $child_correspondence['category'] ) );
            } else {
                if ( is_array( $default_categories ) ) {
                    foreach ( $default_categories as $default_category ) {
                        array_push( $arr_cat, get_cat_ID( $default_category['default_category_name'] ) );
                    }
                } 
            }

        }
        return $arr_cat;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, is there a missing close parentheses in the code sample

Comment: @jspcal, hi, thanks, fixed

Comment: Why doesn't `else` work?

Comment: Please show an example of input values where `else` doesn't work.

Comment: I'll bet anything that the problem is that you're replacing partial words, but you only want to replace whole words. But that's not stated anywhere in the question.

Comment: @Barmar, When the condition is met, then `else {}` is also triggered. I gave a full count. Look here please. Maybe the problem lies in the `$arr_cat` variable?

Comment: That's not possible. Either the `if` or `else` block is triggered, never both.

Comment: Please provide sample input, the expected output, and the wrong output that you're getting.

Comment: Post a [mre] that we can copy and execute. So leave out all those unrelated functions like `get_field()`.

Comment: @Barmar, Can we chat about this? I will show screenshots where you can see the problem.

Comment: Why did you remove the code from the question that shows where the real problem is?

Comment: Please, do not remove the code. It's been referred by on the answers, and by changing the question after it's been answered you invalidate the answers, which is not cool. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the default categories whenever you don't match the keywords in one element of `$correspondence_tables`, but it could match later elements.

The code to add the default categories should only be added if *none* of the keywords in `$correspondence_tables` are matched. You can tell if that happened at the end of the loop by checking if `$arr_cat` is empty.

```
function get_matched_categories( $description_every ) {
    $correspondence_tables = get_field( 'correspondence_table', 'option' );
    $default_categories = get_field( 'default_categories', 'option' );
    if ( is_array( $correspondence_tables ) ) {
        $arr_cat = array();
        foreach ( $correspondence_tables as $child_correspondence ) {

            if ( str_ireplace( explode( ', ', $child_correspondence['keywords'] ), '', $description_every ) != $description_every ) {
                array_push( $arr_cat, get_cat_ID( $child_correspondence['category'] ) );
            }
        }
        if (empty($arr_cat) && is_array($default_categories)) {
            foreach ( $default_categories as $default_category ) {
                array_push( $arr_cat, get_cat_ID( $default_category['default_category_name'] ) );
            }
        } 
        return $arr_cat;
    }
}
```

Comment: This accepted answer is now at best confusing, what with the bulk of the OP's source code removed (both from this answer and OP's question).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$words = "word1, word2, word3";
$text = "This is word1 text word2";

// this is the same code offered in the OP
// changed to make it easier to see the effect
$wordsArray = explode(', ',$words);
$replacedText = str_ireplace($wordsArray,'',$text);
var_dump($replacedText);
if ($replacedText !== $text) {
        echo "some logic".PHP_EOL;
} else {
        echo "no logic".PHP_EOL;
}

// remove all the non-word characters (since we only care about words) and
// split the array on white space and word boundaries
$textArray = preg_split('/[\s\b]+/',preg_replace('/[^\w ]/','',$text));

// use array_intersect to see if there is an intersection between the two arrays
$match = array_intersect($wordsArray,$textArray);
var_dump($wordsArray,$textArray,$match);
if (!empty($match)) {
        echo "some logic".PHP_EOL;
} else {
        echo "some different logic".PHP_EOL;
}
```

If this is to support translation, I'd suggest gettext or a framework

Comment: This may be clearer, but why would it have a different result?

Comment: Thanks, but your code works the same as my code

Comment: Of course it does. It's just pulling the sub-expressions into variables, but doesn't change anything.

Comment: However, this rewrite should make it easier to debug. You can add `echo $replacedText;` so you can see why the replacement didn't do what you expected. @s.kuznetsov

Comment: Updated the answer to offer a different approach.  @barmar

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually trying to *replace* something, or simply need to *match* words?

**If simply to match**, [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) will match and return a boolean for your `if/else` convenience; and [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) will further let you capture all the matches:

```
/* 
 The word-list needs to be a regular expression.
 \b = word-boundary to match whole words, i = case-insensitive 
*/

$words = '~\b(word1|word2|word3)\b~i';

$text = "This is word1 text word2";

// If you simply need to know if there's a match:

if(preg_match($words, $text)) {
    // yes
} else { }

// If you want to process all matched words:

if(preg_match_all($words, $text, $matches)) {
    // yes, these:
    var_dump($matches);
} else { }
```

**If you need to replace**, [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) has a "count" variable populated with the number of replacements. (If you don't need to replace, you're using a hammer for a spanner with `_replace`.)

```
$text = preg_replace($words, '', $text, -1, $count);

if($count > 0) {
    // yes, text changed
} else { }
```

If you prefer to have your working word list comma-separated, just build the regex on the fly:

```
$words_rx = '~\b' 
            . str_replace(', ', '|', $words)
            . '\b~i';
```

Why to use regular expressions here? Instead of abusing `_replace`, we could for example build on `foreach($words as $word) { stripos($text, $word); }` etc. In this case, the answer is simple: we can use`\b`. You want to have a reliable means for identifying word boundaries and matching whole words only. (Thereby `a*void*ing awk*war*d` substring matches.)